# Unable to create call adapter for io.reactivex.Single

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to conncet to server with retrofit and rxjava.it works when I used call and everything is good.but when try to use rxjava ,its getsinto trouble.
the error text:

Could not locate call adapter for io.reactivex.Single

in the build.gradle I implemented the retrofit adapter.but I dont know whats the problem.
this is my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

api client code:

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL="http://192.168.1.100/digikala/";
private static Retrofit retrofit=null;
public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if(retrofit==null){
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();
    }

    return  retrofit;
}
```

api service code:

```
public interface ApiService {

   @GET("readamazing.php")
   Single<List<Product>> getSingleProducts();
 }
```

main acitivity code:

```
ApiService apiService=ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
apiService.getSingleProducts().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Product>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Product> products) {
            Log.i("LOG", "onSuccess: "+products.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.i("LOG", "onSuccess: "+e.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: add error log to your question.

Comment: Could not locate call adapter for io.reactivex.Single

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` *instead of* `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` as `RxJava2` is used.

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```

to the `Retrofit.Builder()`.